# Map array to array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an changing array with selected items, where key is id:

```
[1, 2, 4, 6]
```

And array of objects:

```
items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    selected: false
  }
]
```

How can I map selected array to items and change 'selected' to true and for other items change it to false?

Comment: There are a variety of ways you can accomplish this, however could you provide more details on your use case as there might be a better approach, then to simply iterating through all items and updating the value? For example you could change the `items` array to be a hashmap/object and to look similar to this: `items: {1: {id: 1, selected: false}}`, but it all depends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    selected: false
  }
];
var array = [1, 2, 4, 6];

items.forEach(function(item) {
  item.selected = (array.indexOf(item.id) !== -1);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
items.forEach(item => item.selected = array.contains(item.id))
```

Simply loop through items, setting the selected property based on whether or not the id is contained in the array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and iterate the array and set all `false`, and then the selected to `true`.

```js
var selected = [1, 2, 4, 6],
    items = [{ id: 1, selected: false }, { id: 2, selected: false }, { id: 3, selected: false }, { id: 4, selected: false }, { id: 5, selected: true }, { id: 6, selected: false }],
    map = new Map;

items.forEach(a => (map.set(a.id, a), a.selected = false));
selected.forEach(a => map.get(a).selected = true);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A version with [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var selected = [1, 2, 4, 6],
    items = [{ id: 1, selected: false }, { id: 2, selected: false }, { id: 3, selected: false }, { id: 4, selected: false }, { id: 5, selected: true }, { id: 6, selected: false }],
    set = new Set(selected);

items.forEach(a => a.selected = set.has(a.id));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It seems that `selected` changes, but `items` does not? In that case, the solution should build the map once from `items`, and then have a way to update `items` based on the new `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,2,4,6];
var items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    selected: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    selected: true
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    selected: false
  }
];

var notSelected = $.grep(items, function(e) { return arr.indexOf(e.id) == -1 }).map(function(e) { e.selected = false; return e;});
var selected = $.grep(items, function(e) { return arr.indexOf(e.id) != -1 }).map(function(e) { e.selected = true; return e;});
```

Result:

```
notSelected.concat(selected);
```

Comment: usually better not to provide jQuery solutions unless requested.

Answer (score -1):

Please Try it. I think it will works...

```
$new=array();
foreach($items as $item){
   if($item['selected']==false){
$new.=array_merge($item['id']);
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

And to change non selected items true.

```
foreach($items as $item){
if($item['selected']==false){
$item['selected']=true;
 }
}
```

Comment: What language is this?